# Can parentheses be used for order of operations in Regex?

Tags: regex

I think I have my Regex working, but I'm not completely sure.

The regex is:

```
/(\n([ \t]*)){2,}/
```

The goal originally is to capture two or more new-lines together, so if someone types `\n\n\n\n\n`, I can do something with that.

However, I don't want interference between the consecutive new lines like trailing spaces and tabs...

So I still want to be able to catch `\n   \t   \n\n  \n`.

I'm not sure if the parentheses are overkill.

The outer parenthesis are to signify that I want everything inside:

```
(\n([ \t]*))
```

to happen two or more times.

Then, the inner parentheses:

```
([ \t]*)
```

are to signify that I want any combination of spaces and tabs ranging from none to infinity trailing a \n to be included in that group. The reason for the inner parentheses is because I don't want it to be interpreted as `(\n[ \t])*` where the `\n` is grouped into potentially happening zero to infinity times.

My confusion stems from the fact that parentheses are used for certain things in regex, right? Not sure if it is like math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner parens is not necessary. The Kleene star only works on the last match. In this case it is `[ \t]` not `\n[ \t]`. Note that in regexp every single non-special character is one match operation. Only when you need multiple characters to be counted as a single match operation would you need to use parens.

So, if you want to do "match newline followed by zero or more whitespace" you do:

```
\n[ \t]*
```

But if you want to do "match zero or more newline followed by one whitespace" you do:

```
(\n[ \t])*
```

Comment: I see, but then, my use of the outer parentheses is correct, right? There are two groups, so I need those parentheses.

Comment: @David Yes, the outer parens is correct otherwise the `{2,}` rule would only apply to the whitespace group. And it would be an invalid syntax anyway because `{x,y}` cannot follow `*`

Comment: The statement *the Kleene star only works on the last match* is not appropriate as the `*` quantifier is applied to a part of a  *pattern* it follows, not the *match value*.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer:* "Regex" is not a single thing; rather, it's a family of related notations supported by many different languages and tools. The below explanation pertains to the most widespread forms of regex, such as those of Perl, Java, JavaScript, Python, and PHP.

---

- Yes, parentheses result in grouping, just as in mathematics.
- In addition, parentheses normally "capture" the text they match, allowing the text to be referred to later. For example, `/([a-z])\1/` matches a lowercase ASCII letter, followed by the same letter again. (So, it matches `ee`, but not `ef`.) You can disable this capturing by writing `(?:...)` instead of just `(...)`.
- However, just as in mathematics, you don't always need parentheses, because sometimes the default "order of operations" is appropriate. Just as we don't usually write (2*x*) + 3, because it's equivalent to 2*x* + 3, we don't usually write `\n([ \t]*)`, because it's equivalent to `\n[ \t]*`.

Comment: Technically regex is a singular thing. It specifically refers to Perl compatible regexp. The traditional regular expression is regexp, Perl style is regex. The word "regex" was first coined by Perl programmers to differentiate their regex from traditional regexp

Comment: @slebetman: Nonsense; even Perl libraries for POSIX regexes -- which are *not* Perl-like -- call them "regexes". But even if I accepted the claim that *regex* referred specifically to "Perl compatible" or "Perl style" regexes, my point would still stand, since even with such regexes, there's a lot of variation in the details.

Comment: Actually, it's even more specific than that. Perl programmers were the ones who coined the word "regex" to refer specifically to Perl6 regular expression. This is because Perl6 regex is Turing complete and is therefore no longer a regular expression so people were complaining that calling it regexp is a misnomer. I'm not sure but I think Larry Wall himself came up with regex.

Comment: @slebetman: You should really consider learning to use Google. Your comment is so full of BS that I can't even properly debunk it in this space, but just to give one example -- a minute's research and you would have found that the term "regex" was extremely common *years* before the announcement that there would even *be* a Perl 6.